# How to create 3D DNA Origami struture using cadnano

Tags: bioinformatics

I am learning DNA Origami and came across [cadnano](http://cadnano.org) for creating DNA Origami strutures. 
[image]

I was able to draw Some simple DNA Origami Strutures [green triangle] but having trouble with making complex DNA Origami strutures[ Red star] in cadnano. Do you have any idea how i can create these strutures [red star] using cadnano or do you know any softwares (user friendly) better than cadnano to draw complex 3d strutures

note:picture is taken from cadnano site

Answer (score 2):

You can find the bottom example (with the slotted cross) as a zip file in CadNano's gallery at:
http://cadnano.org/gallery

It doesn't seem like CadNano does a good job at displaying 3D shapes, but you can submit the source file to CanDo for analysis and it'll show up as it does in the gallery images.